# Print the first line of uniq output

Tags: awk, uniq

```
>cat testing.txt
aaa bbb
aaa ccc
xxx yyy
zzz ppp
uuu vvv
uuu ttt
```

I want to display the uniq lines based on the first field and output oly the first occurence of the line

```
aaa bbb
xxx yyy
zzz ppp
uuu vvv
```

When I do:

```
>uniq testing
I get:
aaa bbb
aaa ccc
xxx yyy
zzz ppp
uuu vvv
uuu ttt
```

Which is NOT what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't mind the order

```
$ awk '(!( $1 in arr) ){arr[$1]=$0}END{for(i in arr) print arr[i]}' file
```

Alternatively, you can use Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ane 'BEGIN{h={}}; h[$F[0]]=$_ if not h.has_key?($F[0]) ; END{h.each{|x,y| puts "#{y}" }} ' file
aaa bbb
xxx yyy
zzz ppp
uuu vvv
```

Comment: Thanks!The awk one-liner did just fine!

Answer (score 4):

Another *awk* solution:

```
awk '!_[$1]++' infile
```

Perl:

```
perl -ane'
  print unless $_{$F[0]}++
  ' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you sort your input before passing it to uniq

cat testing.txt | sort | uniq -w3

Answer (score 1):

uniq supports checking only N characters using the -w flag. If your file really looks like this, you can do `uniq -w 3`.

Comment: If the OP's sample data and sample output are representative, this is clearly the best answer.